# "Member for 11m" doesn't make much sense

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I saw this strangeness while viewing a user's aviation profile in the SE iOS app:

> [image]

The user clearly has been a member for longer than 11 minutes.

Comment: It's supposed to say "11 months"; I'm not sure if it's being clipped or if someone actually thought "m" was a suitable abbreviation. Also, I'm assuming this is the iOS app, since that screenshot doesn't look like either the mobile page or the Android app.

Comment: Ah, 11 "months" not "minutes". Ok, I'm not sure if this is a bug or just a UX flaw then.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug - we don't use "m" as an abbreviation for "months" anywhere else that I'm aware (which is why I kinda wonder if they just didn't allow enough space) - note that we *do* use "m" as an abbreviation for "minutes"!

Comment: I have edited this to be a more proper bug report, focusing on the bug itself which is using "m" for months.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, I don't have the proper technologies currently to do so. Or possibly just the proper apps.

Comment: No app, taking a screenshot is a generic action of iOS.

Comment: What about the circle?

Comment: How about pixlr edit? Or just a general paint tool?

Comment: You Doodle seems pretty legit. postingSwag++

Comment: If space is a concern, "mo" would be much better.

Comment: Taking care of this.

Comment: @Shog9 "m" is used to abbreviate months on [the site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) (under site age). "m" is also used for millions there, so that's a little confusing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed – dates will now be rendered in a glorious, full-length format:

[image]

This change will first take effect in **beta build 1.2.1.168**.

Comment: Will it affect other timestamps in the app? Or just profile page?

Comment: Current change is only on the profile page.